# SQL - selecting min value and returning all column information for that min

Tags: sql-server, group-by, min

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

In order to be complete I will show the full query:

```
SELECT 
    final_eqid.eqId, eqPrice.date_, 
    optContract.expDate, optContract.strike,
    MIN(ivListed.ivMid) iv
FROM final_eqid 
    INNER JOIN eqPrice ON final_eqid.eqId = eqPrice.eqId 
    INNER JOIN optContract ON eqPrice.eqId = optContract.eqId 
    INNER JOIN ivListed ON eqPrice.date_ = ivListed.date_ 
        AND optContract.optId = ivListed.optId
WHERE 
    eqPrice.date_ = '2008-01-02' 
    AND final_eqid.eqid = 7
GROUP BY final_eqid.eqid, eqPrice.date_, optContract.expDate, optContract.strike
```

I intentionally chose just one date_ and one eqid but I have thousands of each.

The results are below:

```
 eqId   date_                expDate           strike   iv
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-01-19 00:00:00 25.000  0.9319
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-02-16 00:00:00 25.000  0.6306
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-05-17 00:00:00 25.000  0.5349
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-08-16 00:00:00 25.000  0.5006
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-01-19 00:00:00 30.000  0.5727
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-02-16 00:00:00 30.000  0.5083
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-05-17 00:00:00 30.000  0.2752
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-08-16 00:00:00 30.000  0.4559
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-01-19 00:00:00 35.000  0.3854
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-02-16 00:00:00 35.000  0.4065
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-05-17 00:00:00 35.000  0.4308
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-08-16 00:00:00 35.000  0.4213
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-01-19 00:00:00 40.000  0.3472
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-02-16 00:00:00 40.000  0.37
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-05-17 00:00:00 40.000  0.3969
    7   2008-01-02 00:00:00 2008-08-16 00:00:00 40.000  0.3953
```

What I am trying to get is the min iv strike and all the other information for that row.  In the above data this would have ideally returned

```
eqId    date_   expDate strike  iv
7   1/2/2008    1/19/2008   40  0.3472
7   1/2/2008    2/16/2008   40  0.37
7   1/2/2008    5/17/2008   30  0.2752
7   1/2/2008    8/16/2008   40  0.3953
```

if I do not group by strike then I get the correct numbers but lose the ability to identify the strike that had the min(iv) value

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: You could try using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to use a [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.110).aspx) (CTE), which specifies a temporary result set that you can query on. The [MIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) function used with an [OVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx) clause to divide the result set produced by the FROM clause into partitions to which the function is applied.

Here's an example based on your query (although I haven't tested it out, so caveat emptor):

```
WITH cteData AS
(
    SELECT final_eqid.eqId, 
           eqPrice.date_, 
           optContract.expDate, 
           optContract.strike,  
           ivListed.ivMid iv, 
           MIN(ivListed.ivMid) OVER (PARTITION BY final_eqid.eqId, eqPrice.date_,optContract.expDate) as MinIV
    FROM   final_eqid INNER JOIN
                 eqPrice ON final_eqid.eqId = eqPrice.eqId INNER JOIN
                 optContract ON eqPrice.eqId = optContract.eqId INNER JOIN
                 ivListed ON eqPrice.date_ = ivListed.date_ AND optContract.optId = ivListed.optId
    WHERE eqPrice.date_ ='2008-01-02' and final_eqid.eqid=7
    GROUP BY final_eqid.eqid, eqPrice.date_, optContract.expDate, optContract.strike, ivListed.ivMid
)
select eqId, date_, expDate, strike, iv
from cteData
where cteData.iv=cteData.MinIV
```

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this error message:                                    Column 'ivListed.ivMid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I believe I corrected both errors that you mentioned.  For the second, `MIN(ivListed.isMid)` should have been simple `ivListed.ivMid` and included in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Check the edit history to see specific change, if that description is not clear enough :)

Comment: Any suggestions to avoid my tempdb.mdf file from growing to over 600 gigs and causing a crash because of disk space issues?

Comment: How many rows of data you expecting?  You might try to use `SELECT INTO` a temp/working table instead of a CTE using the same query.

Comment: i tried select into within the suggested code and the same thing happened but I had both CTE and Select Into.  That said, I tried just the CTE first.  I am not sure how to implement this without the CTE.  Could I trouble you to provide the select into option?  thanks much in advance :-)   BTW, about 8 million rows